# Is it possible to highlight the previous selected values of a Blazorise Select List?

Tags: c#, datagrid, blazor, selectlist, blazorise

in my Blazor Project i try a Datagrid with Blazorise. For one value i have a (Multi)SelectList in the EditTemplate to select one or more entries from the shipment table. I would like to highlight the previous selected shipments in case the user reopen the selected visit in "Edit Mode". Is this possible?
Regards Lars

```
<DataGridSelectColumn Field="@nameof(Visit.VisitShipment)" Caption="Lieferung" Width="600px" Sortable Editable>
                <DisplayTemplate>
                    @if (context != null)
                        {
                            <div>
                                @foreach (var visitShipment in allVisitShipments.Where(v => v.VisitId == context.Id).ToList())
                                {
                                    
                                    var shipment = allShipments.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == visitShipment.ShipmentId);
                                    if (shipment != null)
                                    {
                                        <div>@($"{shipment.OrderNo} - {shipment.ShipToName}")  </div>
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
                        }
                    </DisplayTemplate>
                    <EditTemplate>
                        <SelectList Multiple
                                TItem="Shipment"
                                TValue="int"
                                Data="@openShipments"
                                TextField="@((item) => item.OrderNo + ", " + item.ShipToName)"
                                ValueField="@((item) => item.Id )"
                                @bind-SelectedValues="@selectedVisitShipment"                                
                                DefaultItemText="Bitte Auftrag auswählen" />
                    </EditTemplate>
                    </DataGridSelectColumn>
```

I thought the reason for this is a problem with my selectedVisitShipment . So i tried several ways to update selectedVisitShipment and openShipments but with but without success. I have to say that i am a newbie to all this stuff.

Comment: It should based on this: `@bind-SelectedValues="@bindSelectedValues="@selectedVisitShipment"`  What type is selectedVisitShipment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint was good. I had made a mistake in my thinking. The `selectedVisitShipment` list was still empty. I have now triggered the update via a `SelectedRowChanged`. Now, the entries are marked in edit mode. I also changed to `@bind-SelectedValues="@selectedVisitShipment"`. Now it works.